# Codeigniter .htaccess re writing

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter

I am try to publish my website as test period.. My domain is http://my_domain.me for example and the codeigniter folder (ci) and I have edited the htaccess file as the following:

```
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond $1!^(index\.php|user_guide|frontend|backend) 
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://my_domain.me/ci/index.php/$1 [L]
```

And it doesn't work, I got error 500 when I request my website?
Any help please..

Comment: Did you check the manual? http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/urls.html There's an example `.htaccess` there.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|user_guide|frontend|backend|robots\.txt)
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /ci/index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: any other project do u have on same server ?

Comment: yes I have some php files.. but I uploaded my codeigniter project as a separated directory (ci) where is the problem?

Comment: any other .htaccess file is there ?

Comment: There is no any other htaccess file

Comment: Yes I did and it works, but now it required index.php before any page name

Comment: i think u need to enable mod_rewrite in php.ini

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^/?ci/(index\.php|user_guide|frontend|backend|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /ci/index.php/$1 [L]
```

But depending on how you have CI setup, it may not be reading the path info, you could also try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /ci/ [L]
```

in your document root, then have this in your CI folder:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /ci/
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|user_guide|frontend|backend|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: shoud I put `RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /ci/ [L]` in www?

Comment: @Mahmoudco whereever your document root is, essentially where you'd end up if you just went to `http://yourdomain.com/`

Comment: @Mahmoudco look in your webserver's error logs and see what it says is causing the error.

Answer (score 0):

`Error 500` is usually annoying. However, there is a very easy way to check what the error is. On your server, go and check your Apache or PHP error log, it should tell you what is causing the error.

You might find that it's just a missing semi-colon